# Kivy Android and Kivy linux different collors

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors, kivy

I'm creating a image background for my application using Gimp. The background color value in html notation is `8f9aff`. I created this background and put on my widget canvas. When I run my application on my linux pc I can see my widget with a background color `8f9aff` that I choose. Although, on my Android phone I can't see my widget color as `8f9aff`, it appears more like `a08afd`. If I take a screenshot of my phone with "`a08afd`" color and send to my pc it "backs" to `8f9aff` color.

This is my Gimp screenshot:
[image: gimp image]

This is my application on linux:
[image: application on linux]

And this is a image with the approximate color that I get on my Android phone.
[image]

How can I fix problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a Samsung phone?  Have a look at [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73280/color-differences-android-vs-laptop-and-iphone).  Samsung phones use a unique layout of pixels that differs from the iPhone and from most laptop and desktop screens and which seems like it will lead to slight color differences.

Each screen is going to display a color a little bit differently based on its calibration, pixel layout, brightness, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. Yes, I have a Samsung phone. The given link helped me to understand what is happening.